# Why doesn't exclude work when working with middleware?

Tags: nestjs

I have an AppModule where I use middleware

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
            .apply(AuthMiddleware)
            .exclude(
                { path: '/api/users', method: RequestMethod.POST },
                { path: '/api/users/login', method: RequestMethod.POST }
            )
            .forRoutes('');
    }
}
```

Also I have my AuthMiddleware

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private userService: UserService) {
    }

    async use(req: RequestModel, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

        try {
            const tokenArray: string[] = req.headers['authorization'].split(' ');
            const decodedToken = await this.authService.verifyJwt(tokenArray[1]);
            const user: UserI = await this.userService.getOne(decodedToken.user.id);

            if (user) {
                req.user = user;
                next();
            } else {
                throw new HttpException('Unauthorized', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        } catch {
            throw new HttpException('Unauthorized', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

In theory, middleware should not be used for the api/users/login route, but it is used, this is what it outputs:
{
"statusCode": 401,
"message": "Unauthorized"
}